# How to loop around the ascii values of the alphabet in Matlab

Tags: matlab, modulo

I am new to Matlab and am having trouble using the `mod` function.

I am given a scrambled vector of lowercase characters and a shift value that can be positive or negative that I am supposed to add to the vector
I am supposed to use the mod function to wrap around the lowercase letters in the alphabet.
For example, if the letter is '`a`' and the shift amount if 4 the letter will then become '`e`'.
A negative means shifting towards '`a`' in the alphabet.
 The Shift should '`wrap`' around the alphabet- '`x`' shifted by 7 should become '`e`'.

I have tried writing conditionals using if and `elseif` statements but I am supposed to use the `mod` function instead of conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mod(x,y)` is the remainder of the division of `x` and `y`, having the same sign as `y`. Thus, given negative `x`, the sign is still positive. This is different from how `mod` is defined in other languages.

I obviously `y` must be the number of characters in the range a-z. `x` is the 0-based index to the shifted character, which should be 0 for “a”, and `y-1` for “z”. You can get this by simple subtracting the ASCII value of “a”:

```
letter - 'a'
```

Note that `'a'` is a char that implicitly converts to the ASCII value of the letter in arithmetic operations.

The result of the `mod` operation then again returns one such index, which you can turn into a character by adding the ASCII value of “a”:

```
char(index + 'a')
```

Putting it all together:

```
char(mod(letter-'a', 'z'-'a'+1) + 'a')
```

Instead of `letter` you can use a vector of letters (char array) in that expression.